# How do I handshake with websocket in python?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, screen-scraping, scrape

I want to perform a handshake with this websocket

```
wss://ws.qxbroker.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket
```

I need to dump this data to authenticate as far as I understand

```
42["authorization",{"session":"oZA1xa5d4DYvNJoxxxxxxO","isDemo":1}]
```

whatever I try my connection is getting closed

here is my code so far

```
from websocket import create_connection
import json


# Launch the connection to the server.
ws = create_connection('wss://ws.qxbroker.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket')

# Perform the handshake.
ws.send(json.dumps('42["authorization",{"session":"oZA1xa5d4DYvNJoe4kZhL911QxxxxxxxxxxsPCSTMO","isDemo":1}]'))

# Printing all the result
while True:
    try:
        result = ws.recv()
        print(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

**webocket site : https://qxbroker.com**

Comment: Why do you call json.dumps?

Comment: @user253751 i took this template from another answer. but tried removing that and still my connection is getting closed.

Comment: @user253751 any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: solved my problem adding the header `'Origin': 'https://qxbroker.com'` to the connection.

And you don't need to use json.dumps on the ws.send method